# How to setup Cometd in Spring Boot with Jetty?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-jetty, cometd, wicketstuff

CometdPushService.get() throws NullPointerException

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicketstuff-push-cometd</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0-M5</version>
    </dependency>
```

TimerPushService.get() works as excepted but would like to use Cometd to manage bandwidth.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.wicketstuff.push.cometd.CometdPushService.<init>(CometdPushService.java:133)
 at org.wicketstuff.push.cometd.CometdPushService.get(CometdPushService.java:107)
 at org.wicketstuff.push.cometd.CometdPushService.get(CometdPushService.java:97)
```

Found this good post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cometd-users/Kn13KSHqrAw however it fails at start up with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/Timeout
at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.<init>(BayeuxServerImpl.java:89)
at com.erranda.prototype.WebsocketConfiguration.bayeuxServer(WebsocketConfiguration.java:78)
at com.erranda.prototype.WebsocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e079365.CGLIB$bayeuxServer$4(<generated>)
at com.erranda.prototype.WebsocketConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e079365$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44de86de.invoke(<generated>)
```

Comment: Seems you are just missing a dependency on `jetty-util-<version>.jar`.

Comment: I did add the jetty-util, and I can see it in the dependency tree with starter-jetty. I think cometd might be using an older version as Timeout class wasn't in the package. Classpath hell.